MySQL Having + OrderBy returning fewer rows than expected
I have the following query:
select 
    products.id,
    products.description,
    products.barcode,
    getStock(products.id, 'Production') AS total_stock   
from `products`
having total_stock > 0
order by products.description asc

Which is pretty straight forward. However, the results returned are incorrect. It's currently returning 2 rows and if I remove the order by clause it returns 4000 rows.
select 
    products.id,
    products.description,
    products.barcode,
    getStock(products.id, 'Production') AS total_stock   
from `products`
having total_stock > 0 

Applying a group by clause, like referred in enumerous topics such as Error with ORDER BY used with HAVING Clause, has no success, as the number of rows returned is, again, 2.
select 
    products.id,
    products.description,
    products.barcode,
    getStock(products.id, 'Production') AS total_stock   
from `products`
group by products.id, products.description, products.barcode 
having total_stock > 0 
order by products.description asc

What am I missing?

Edit 1: The getStock function
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION getStock (productId INT, environment VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS INT(11)
BEGIN                 
    DECLARE qty INT(11) DEFAULT 0;
    
    SELECT SUM(pw.stock) INTO qty
        FROM products_wholesalers AS pw
        INNER JOIN subscriptions AS subscription ON subscription.id = pw.subscription_id
        WHERE pw.product_id = productId 
            AND pw.active = true
            AND subscription.type = 'Wholesaler'
            AND subscription.active = true
            AND subscription.environment = environment;
    
    RETURN qty;
END $$


What does getStock do? Can you share the implementation?

Check for EXPLAIN plans for any differences. There might be something there.

The only difference in EXPLAIN is showing "Using filesort" information in the Extra tab, depending if I apply the ORDER BY or not. Yes, I can share the getStock function, post updated.

@damjad dunno if this helps, but I just tested on a different machine and the query (with ORDER BY clause) works great. Could this be related to the MySQL version? On the machine with errors the MySQL version is 5.7.44, while the machine where it worked is 10.4.27

5.7.44 is a version of MySQL, but 10.4.27 is a version of MariaDB. These are different databases, with numerous incompatible features. MariaDB forked from MySQL in 2010, but both products have continued to change independently since then, and by now you shouldn't consider MariaDB to be a "type of MySQL."

@BillKarwin You're right, it shows indeed 10.4.27-MariaDB. It comes with Xampp.

Also: 5.7 is no longer supported by anyone, to the point of no longer even getting security patches. Best to retire the 5.7 system.

The issue is related to how SQL are processed, with 'HAVING' and 'ORDER BY' combination. Your query return 4000 rows because it's not sorting the results by description so it returns all rows meet HAVING condition.
In SQL, HAVING clause filters results after grouping done by the GROUP BY clause and ORDER BY clause sorts rows in the result set before it's returned.
To solve, you can try to use a subquery
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        products.id,
        products.description,
        products.barcode,
        getStock(products.id, 'Production') AS total_stock   
    FROM `products`
) AS subquery
WHERE total_stock > 0
ORDER BY description ASC;


Tested and works, but now I might have a bigger problem. I'll have to translate this into a laravel project and handle relations. Give me a moment.
